# Reading fits file in python

Tags: python, fits, pyfits

I have a problem reading data from a fits file. Usually i can read data from a fits file just fine but now I have some data files which gives me some problems.
When I try to read the file, which should contain three columns and a header, all i get is a table of numbers looking something like this:

[[ 64 195  45 ...,   0   0   0]]

Now this is integers and the data file really should contain three columns containing double and floats in three columns like this:

[9819.3801,     0.00000,        0.00000  ]

[9820.0025,     5.50764e-16,    1.62396e-16  ]

[820.6248,     -3.75781e-17,    1.51864e-16]

I know that I should get these values because a package in IDL called [mrdfits](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/mrdfits.html) can be used to retrieve the values. I have tried looking into which data type the fits file contain and which formats, my code looks something like this:

```
f=pyfits.open('filename')

dat =f[1].data

print f.info

>> No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format

>> 0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU       4  ()            uint8

>> 1    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU     576  (156288, 1)   uint8

>> None

print pyfits.getval('filename','xtension',1)

>> BINTABLE

print dat

>> [[ 64 195  45 ...,   0   0   0]]
```

My question is basically; is there another way I can read in the data so that it gives me the three columns of non-integer data? I am wondering if it is because the file is a BINTABLE that it is read in a different way than normally? Is there another way I can load the three columns than what I do at the moment?
If you need me to clarify some points please ask, as I have tried out a number of things at the moment I am not sure which direction to take it.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have PyFITS downloaded, you are ready to go! To use PyFITS and obtain the information form the FITS file, here is a small example that uses three columns.

```
import pyfits

# Load the FITS file into the program
hdulist = pyfits.open('Your FITS file name here')

# Load table data as tbdata
tbdata = hdulist[1].data

fields = ['J','H','K'] #This contains your column names
var = dict((f, tbdata.field(f)) for f in fields) #Creating a dictionary that contains
                                                 #variable names J,H,K

#Now to call column J,H and K just use
J = var['J']   
H = var['H']
K = var['K']
```

Now the above example has three columns, with headers `J,H,K`. You can now call them by saying `J,H,K` respectively.

What you are doing in your code is that you are printing `f.info` which will only give you the information of the headers and other stuff of your FITS file. It will not print the columns and the information.

Comment: I have edited the original question. Maybee this will clarify my question, because usually I don't have any trouble using PyFits its just this set of data that seems weird. however I don't think the data file has been corrupted but maybee I am reading it in in the wrong way for this data type..